# I have not being able to get scrollspy to work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been trying for the past 4 hours but I am obviously doing something wrong. Should the scrollspy components be placed in a separate div, am I missing something else? I have checked many examples and questions but can't figure it out. One thing I can't do is set the position to relative, as it messes up some other things. I have added Bootstrap js at the end of the HTML file.

This is the JSFiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/o78x2ezn/1/

```
              <body data-bs-spy="scroll" data-bs-target="#navbar" data-bs-offset="50">
      
            <nav id="navbar" class="navbar fixed-top navbar-custom navbar-expand-sm">
              <div class="container-fluid">
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-offset="50" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                  <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link py-1 d-md-inline-block active" href="#home">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link py-1 d-md-inline-block" href="#skills">Skills</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link py-1 d-md-inline-block" href="#projects">Projects</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link py-1 d-md-inline-block" href="#about">About</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </nav>
```

So there are 2 issues, first is that the the navbar buttons stay in the active state for only a moment when clicked, otherwise they are never in the active state.

Comment: Please create a sfiddle.net, Its easy to test and fix issues there.

Comment: Sure thing, this is it

https://jsfiddle.net/o78x2ezn/1/

Comment: Great. On which element you want to add position relative?

Comment: That's the exact problem, I know it has to be on the body, but if I add it, then the positioning of the other elements messes up.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your bootstrap with:

`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>`

add `position:relative;` to body and wrap your all sections below nav with
`<div class="wrapper">`
and set wrapper position to relative .

Comment: And I should as the bootstrap js at the end of the file, right?
Also, after wrapping everything below nav in class="wrapper", do I have to set the position of the wrapper class as relative?

Comment: Yes, always put script files at the end.

Comment: I did both things but the problem still persists. Maybe I am making some errors somewhere. Thanks a lot for helping!

Answer (score 0):

that's beccause of Scrollspy ignore the target elements that are not visible.

you should change these three class styles :

```css
.skills-align {
  visibility: hidden;
}

 {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.about-align {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

to this :

```css
.skills-align, .projects-align, .about-align {
  visibility: visible;
}
```